# ZF: ZEND_NAVIGATION_PAGE - page doesn't get active status

Tags: php, zend-framework, tree, zend-navigation

I have generated menu with pages like that:

```
$pageSettings = array(
                    'route'      => 'catalog',
                    'label'      => $element->getName(),
                    'module'     => 'default',
                    'controller' => 'catalog',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                    'params'     => array('cat' => $element->getUrl()),
                    'order'      => $element->getOrder(),
                    'id'         => 'catalogID_' . $element->getId(),
);

$contentMenuTree->addPage($pageSettings);
```

Where `$contentMenuTree` is a Zend_Navigation instance.

And have a route in a bootstrap:

```
$router->addRoutes(array(            
    'catalog'  => new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/catalog/:cat', array('module' => 'default', 'controller' => 'catalog', 'index' => 'index', 'cat' => null))
));
```

If I call site.ru/catalog/test then there are nothing active page in $contentMenuTree.

So I found patch for it but it doesn't seem correct:

```
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$action = $front->getRequest()->getActionName();
$cat    = $front->getRequest()->getParam('cat');
$module = $front->getRequest()->getModuleName();
$controller = $front->getRequest()->getControllerName();

if ($controller == 'catalog' && $module == 'default' 
             && $action == 'index' && $cat==$element->getUrl())
                        $pageSettings['active'] = true;
```

Why zend_navigation doesn't get active page element automatically?

Comment: whats not working in the patch ? how do you set the pageSettings ?

Comment: In the patch all is working perfect.
But I think that Zend_Navigation should work without this patch.

Comment: you are right, ZF Navigation takes care of params too. does /catalog/index/cat/xyz work ?

Comment: see example #4 on http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.navigation.pages.html#zend.navigation.pages.mvc as far as i see it you make it perfectly right.
Does $element->getUrl() return the correct value of 'cat' ?
`vardump($navigation->toArray());`

Comment: you don't have `action` in your router

Comment: /catalog/index/cat/xyz works as a page, but it is not active page anyway.
$element->getUrl() has always parameter, its for sure.
I printed $navigation->toArray(): If I remove patch, then all pages are not active.

Comment: @ venimus. Yup, you're right)) Many thx. I wasted 3 hours to find it)))
Could you make your post as an answer please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't have `action` in your router

i think it should be

```
$router->addRoutes(array(            
    'catalog'  => new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/catalog/:cat', 
     array('module' => 'default', 
           'controller' => 'catalog', 
           'action' => 'index',
           'cat' => null))
));
```